# A decent over night sleep at Brussels Charleroi Airport

Tags: airports, sleeping, opening-hours, crl

Is it possible to arrive at night and sleep for a couple of hours inside the Brussels Charleroi Airport before taking an early flight?
If so, are there any decent places to sleep/rest?

Comment: It might help if you add specific times, at what time do you plan on entering the airport and when is your flight scheduled to leave?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this [Sleeping in Airports](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/guides/brussels-charleroi-airport-guide.htm) article, the airport is open 24h, but you'll probably have to sleep on the floor:

> The airport is open 24 hours, but overnight campers will have to stay landside until security checkpoints open around 4:00AM. Seating is very limited and most have armrests, so bring along a blanket or sleep mat to rest a little easier on the cold floor. The far end of Terminal 1 has large windows and some private nooks. Do expect security guards to wake you up to check IDs or as the airport gets busy. For uninterrupted sleep, nearby hotels offer shuttle service.

Comment: There was some chairs where you could sit up and try to sleep in, but nothing comfortable. You could also find some corners and try to sleep on the stone floor. Either way, nothing recommended.